# How to change the color of a compilation error at Netbeans

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

I have a dark GTK theme applied at my Ubuntu system, and I need to change the color of a compilation error at Netbeans 7.2.1.

[image: This] is how it looks when there are errors at a build.
The background is dark grey, the Make output is white and the error is blue.

I tried changing, both *URL* and *Hyperlinks* categories at **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Syntax > All languages**, and also at **Fonts & Colors > Highlighting > Hyperlinks**, still nothing. I even tried searching at the Annotations tab, and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Fonts & Colors" are only for the editor. As far as I can tell, your screen shot shows the content of the output window, not the editor.

I don't have a 7.2.1 around any more (that's way too old), but in 7.4 you can configure the output window through "Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Output -> Important Link Color"

Comment: Yes, the screenshot shows the content of the output window. I've downloaded v7.4 and this solved my problems.